# Can I use DRF to recreate the ORO CRM API to get custom functionalities for my project

Tags: django-rest-framework, orocrm

This might seem stupid but I've had this question for a long while. I've been using ORO CRM DB and its API for a while now. Its really one of the good open source CRMs. I just wanted to know if I can use their database and create a Django REST framework around it and create the same functionality of what ORO API is offering.

I would rather build the API with DRF than learn PHP to get the functionality that I need. So is this question. Kindly help me in figuring this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR
Yes for read, but using application database is a bad practice.

Explanation.
In Oro codebase there is a lot of triggers (listeners, queue message emitters) that could be fired during the CRUD operations, you can't use another code base to just mimic it.
Actually you can try to use DRF for read operation, that is rarely trigger any events, but doing this (use external db that is tend to change) is a bad practice.

You can try to explain your use case to get more context of what you are trying to achieve.